# How DO I get JSON String And display Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, vb.net

My webservice return the JSON string and I am trying to Accesses  JSOn String In MASTERPage.master How Can I do ? "GetJson()" Method is return the JSOn string . I am trying to Display that JSON String but its Failed. Does It is Problem in MasterPage.MAster ? Can we Call ajax In master Page ?

**Webservice Method:**

```
    <WebMethod()> _
Public Function MasterMenu() As String

    ' Dim dt As New DataTable("MenuMaster")

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT ID, MENU_NAME FROM SMT_MENU_MASTER order by menu_name"
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Query)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                sda.Fill(dt)
            End Using
        End Using

        Dim sData As String = GetJson(dt)

        Return sData





    End Using



End Function
```

**Ajax Method In Masterpage.master**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
              $.ajax({

                  type: "POST",
                  url: 'Menu.asmx/MasterMenu',
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success: function (response) {
                      alert("i am in");
                      alert(response.d);
                  }, error: function (response) {
                      alert("Failed to load data");

                  }

              });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
          $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({

              type: "POST",
              url: 'Menu.asmx/MasterMenu',
              data: "{}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  alert("i am in");
                  alert(data.sData);
              }, error: function (response) {
                  alert("Failed to load data");

              }

          });
      });
```

use  to see complete json and its structure.`console.log(data);`

Comment: try error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert(jqXHR.responseText);
      }        to get what error you are facing in fetching json if nothing is printed on console

Comment: its show only web service with [script service] attribute called on page

Answer (score 0):

Your webmethod should be **Shared**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function MasterMenu() As String

    ' Dim dt As New DataTable("MenuMaster")

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT ID, MENU_NAME FROM SMT_MENU_MASTER order by menu_name"
    Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("constr").ConnectionString
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(Query)
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Connection = con
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                sda.Fill(dt)
            End Using
        End Using

        Dim sData As String = GetJson(dt)

        Return sData

    End Using

End Function 

 $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({

              type: "POST",
              url: 'Menu.asmx/MasterMenu',
              data: "{}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  console.log(data);
                  alert(data);
              }, error: function (response) {
                  alert("Failed to load data");

              }

          });
      });
```

Comment: i make webmethod to Shared but its same The ajax Call Failure and Display Message Failed TO Load Data

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with Web service i have add

```
  <WebService(Namespace:="http://tempuri.org/")> _
  <WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo:=WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)> _
  <Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
  <System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()> _
```

and Also Import Reference DLL. now Problem Is solved I can call web-service Using Ajax and Retrieve Data On Master Page

DLL  :

`Imports Newtonsoft.Json`